Why can't I pass "Mouse Y" (from Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") straight into the X axis transform rotation in this situation? (Want to learn more about C#)
Noob/beginner here. I have searched this issue but haven’t found anything on it myself (apologies if this has already been solved/ answered on here). I’m making a super basic FP character controller following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmIPqGqp8UY). It’s great and I’ve got it working, but I ran into some problems along the way and I’m really interested as to why. The final script looks like this (missing some code to lock the mouse to centre of screen):
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementScript_V3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform playerChar_FP_POV = null;
    [SerializeField] float mouseSensitivty = 3.5f;
    float cameraPitch = 0.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       PlayerCameraControl(); 
    }

    public void PlayerCameraControl()
    {
        Vector2 mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        cameraPitch -= mouseDelta.y;
        cameraPitch = Mathf.Clamp(cameraPitch, -90.0f, 90.0f);

        playerChar_FP_POV.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * cameraPitch;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseDelta.x * mouseSensitivty);
    }
}

Where the SerializeField Transform “playerChar_FP_POV” is a field which has had a camera (child object of “PlayerChar_Body”) dragged into it so its transform is accessible from the script (see attached image no.1Image showing what Serialize field transform is attached to
While I was experimenting, I found I couldn’t pass "mouseDelta.y" directly into the “PlayerChar_FP_POV” X rotation transform (second last line of script above) the same way I passed mouseDelta.x into the “PlayerChar_Body” Z rotation transform (last line of script above). I first had to create a float “cameraPitch” then assign its value to the inverse of mouseDelta.y (cameraPitch -= mousedelta.y), then clamp the range of “cameraPitch” with Mathf.Clamp (script above- in the last method). Then and only then could I successfully pass the value into “player_FP_Pov” to alter its X rotation transform. If I tried passing mousedelta.y straight into X transform of "playerChar_FP_POV" like so (look in the last method):
    public void PlayerCameraControl()
    {
        Vector2 mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        playerChar_FP_POV.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * mouseDelta.y;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseDelta.x * mouseSensitivty);
    }

(passing mouseDelta.y straight into “playerChar_FP_POV” X rotation transform; leaving out clamping camera range and inverting input)
The X rotation transform of the “PlayerChar_FP_POV” (the players camera) is locked into place and does not respond to mouse Y axis movement (see picture). Parent object can follow mouse x axis on its Z axis, child object cannot follow mouse Y axis on it's x axis
Again, I have the controller working fine. But purely from an educational perspective, I’m trying to figure out why the latter code block doesn’t work. I feel like understanding that would further my understanding a tad more. I hope this was clear enough, don't want to waste peoples time!
Unity Version: 2022.3.22f1
Cheers for reading this!!!
Problem explained above, this section is not entirely applicable.

if you read on the transform class, position is settable but position.x (or y or z) is not. It is frustrating when maybe all you wanna do is nudge x, but, you end up doing transform.position += a_vector; where it might be (0.05,0,0)

It's because Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") aka mouseDelta.y is how much the mouse has moved vertically in the time since the previous frame, which is to say the previous time Update was called.

In the first example, cameraPitch acts as a way to record the state of the rotation as it was on the previous frame:
Vector2 mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

cameraPitch -= mouseDelta.y; // cameraPitch was what we used to set the
                             // local x rotation last frame and we increase
                             // or decrease it based on mouseDelta.y
// < clamping code here >

playerChar_FP_POV.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * cameraPitch;

In this way, it is being used to make a change from the rotation based on the previous frame, which is consistent with how mouseDelta.y is itself a change based on the previous frame.

In the 2nd example, it is attempted to be used on its own as an absolute measure of rotation. Note that nothing about the rotation in the previous frame is involved in any way, it is just overwritten entirely:
Vector2 mouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

// here, playerChar_FP_POV.localEulerAngles still has the rotation
// is had at the end of the last frame

// but then it's overridden... goodbye to whatever it was before!
playerChar_FP_POV.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * mouseDelta.y;

// Too late to do any clamping here... Not good if you want to avoid
// euler angle shenanigans.

By the way, note that there's no clamping involved... so even if you only adjusted the localEulerAngles based on the prior value, weird things can start happening if you go beyond looking up and down if you are only working with euler angles

A little metaphor for further illustration:
Bob starts with 90 apples. Every day, Alice gives or takes a certain number of apples to/from Bob. You are allowed to ask Alice how may apples she gave/took to/from Bob on the current day.
If you need to predict how many apples Bob currently has at the end of every day... you can't just take the amount Alice tells you as your answer, right? You need to remember how many Bob had at the start and then update that amount based on the amount Alice took or gave.
You are basically doing this but with degrees the mouse is "giving" or "taking" to/from the rotation.
